# Loud grinding noise and blurred printouts on Samsung CLP-620ND laser printer

Tags: hardware-failure, laser-printer

I have a Samsung CLP-620ND printer that has suddenly started making loud grinding noises every time it prints.  It also blurs parts of the printouts most of the time as though something is smearing the toner prior to the paper reaching the fuser.

The [service manual](http://www.scribd.com/doc/57790064/SAMSUNG-CLP-620ND-Series-Service-Manual) for this model of printer does not seem to cover noise, and the print quality troubleshooting in this manual does not seem to describe the problem.  One review of the printer (that I can no longer find) suggested that the problem might be the paper transfer belt.  Before I spend $130+ on a new paper transfer belt, I'd like to know if anyone agrees with this assessment.

What are the likely causes of this problem?  How can I fix it?  Are there parts I will need to replace?

Comment: Pull it apart and look :-) Clear out the paper dust (which is slipery) check the rollers gears and belts, and the paper transfer conveyor belt. I would not spend a penny more on it, until I could attempt to discover the actual problem, a rip in the conveyor or something.  Get a point light flashlight and start looking into the nooks and crannies for small torn papers or anything.  Dont touch the heads, but the rubber rollers can be cleaned with a microfiber rag (no lint) and a mix using consumer ammonia.  Spend extra time making sure things are seated and mate well too.

Answer (score 3):

This is going to be almost impossible for anyone else to diagnose. It might be the paper transfer roller (I saw one reference to 50,000 pages for it - how many does the printer have on it?). It might be a broken gear. It might be something else entirely.

I hate to say it, but with a replacement part that costs half as much as the printer, plus your time (or someone else's) for replacements if it requires any disassembly, is it worth repair? The printers appear to be available for $250-300 with shipping

Comment: I'll have to check the counter, but it shouldn't be anywhere near 50.000 pages.  The printer just doesn't get used _that_ much.  As for just buying a new printer, I have considered that also, depending what the actual problem is and what it would cost to fix.

Comment: I've dealt with the situation recently with some Brother printers that call for replacement of the laser and fuser at 100,000 pages - it's a ship-it-to-our-depot repair, and the parts cost ~10% less than a new multifunction of the same or later model, so it's basically a case of use it until the quality deteriorates, then replace. Even with that, the TCO was still lower than comparable HP alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

I understand from your post that the printer is out of warranty, or you wouldn't be posting this here.

While I agree with @fencepost that the printer might not be worth fixing, I would like to make
one remark in the case that you decide to repair it.

Before committing yourself to buying a $130+ part, you should be very sure that this is the real
problem. If you do not have the technical competence to analyze the problem, find someone who has.
In the worse case, bring the printer to a repairshop - the additional cost will work in your favor
as insurance upon the quality of the repair. You could also ask them for an estimate before
doing the actual repair.

Last remark: Don't use the printer any more until it is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I have this printer and it has performed flawlessly for several years until I recently got this mysterious grinding noise from the paper tray. The answers above don't really explain what happens. I was able to fix it myself for about $20 and with a little investigative work. 
While it certainly could be other things, the first thing to look at is the lower tray paper roller in the middle of the lower tray. This can be easily seen when one opens the spring loaded paper feed door at the front of the tray. Looking inside you will see a yellowish rubber strip that is supposed to wrap around the feed roller. In my case, the rubber had become brittle and one side literally detached from the roller which caused  the spindle to get wedged from the loose rubber, and unable to rotate as it is supposed to when paper is fed. The noise comes from the gears at the side of the paper tray and reflects the gears spinning but because the spindle is frozen, they have no choice but to skip, thus creating the noise. The part is readily available and takes about 30 minutes to replace.
Beats throwing a perfectly good printer away!!!

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same noisy issue when printing. By opening the front door of the printer, where you would normally insert the cartridges, I noticed that the thin sheet of black material on the unit that sits in the door, had a piece of what looked like rubber protruding from inside the unit. The side of it showed that it is a replaceable object. To be clear, this is the unit that sits in the door that faces the 4 cartridges.

Tony S.